# Most efficient way to tell if an entity exists in Doctrine 2

Tags: php, doctrine, doctrine-orm

I'm creating a registration form and want to check to see if an email is not already associated with an account. All the ways I can see will create the entire User entity, but I just need to know if it exists.

Comment: I haven't yet migrated to Symfony 2, but in Symfony 1, you would add a `sfValidatorDoctrineUnique` to the form's validator schema.  Does a similar concept not exist in Symfony 2?

Comment: I'm not using Doctrine inside Symfony.

Comment: Good point.  That'll teach me to ignore the fact that a question's not tagged with a framework (:

Answer (score 10, accepted):

```
  public function isUnusedEmail($email) {
    $em = static::$pimple['em'];
    $dql = 'SELECT 1 FROM App\Model\User user WHERE user.email = :email';
    $query = $em->createQuery($dql);
    $query->setParameter('email', $email);

    $res = $query->getResult();
    return empty($res);
  }
```

Answer (score 4):

Consider the following method:

```
/**
 * @param string $token
 * @return bool
 */
public function isTokenUnique($token)
{
    $manager = $this->getEntityManager();

    /** @var Doctrine\ORM\Query $query */
    $query = $manager->
        createQuery('SELECT 1 FROM AppBundle:Member m WHERE m.token = :token')
            ->setParameter('token', $token)
            ->setMaxResults(1)
    ;

    return (count($query->getResult()) == 0);
}
```

Notice a call to `setMaxResults()`. It can be important in some cases.